# Combine lists of dataframes into new list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two lists whose elements are dataframes and both the lists are of equal lengths.

```
df_list1=[]

df_list2=[]
```

I want to merge the dataframes from two lists and put it in a new list

```
new_list=[]

for i in df_list1:
    new_list.append(pd.concat([df_list1[i],df_list2[i]]))
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient(faster) way to do this.

Comment: Are you going to concat `new_list` when you're done?

Comment: No. It will be a list of dataframes

Comment: Then I don't think there is any more efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: ohh okay, I was wondering if I could avoid for loop

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you're going to join all the dataframes together at some point, I don't think you can really get it any faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is a little faster, but the gain in execution time is very minimal.

I compared the following with 2 identical lists of 6 identical DataFrames.

**For loop:**

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    new_lst.append(pd.concat([list1[i], list2[I]]))
```

**List Comprehension:**

```
new_lst = [pd.concat([df1, df2]) for df1, df2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

I ran them 5 times in a row. The table below tallies the runtime in seconds.

| for loop | list comprehension | Diff | % decrease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.008312225341796875 | 0.0009374618530273438 | 0.007374763 | 0.887218908 |
| 0.001142263412475586 | 0.0010223388671875000 | 0.000119925 | 0.104988918 |
| 0.001358985900878906 | 0.0011126995086669922 | 0.000246286 | 0.181228070 |
| 0.001115322113037109 | 0.0008866786956787109 | 0.000228643 | 0.205002138 |
| 0.001134634017944336 | 0.0009284019470214844 | 0.000206232 | 0.181760874 |

I have no idea why the large difference in the first execution but a few more iterations resulted in similar patterns we see in the last 3 rows.